# Make "qgis:delaunaytriangulation" and "qgis:dissolve" save their outputs on a specific predefined layer

Tags: qgis, python, layers, algorithm, dissolve

I'm new to python and QGIS. I'm working on modifying a plugin which runs algorithms "qgis:delaunaytriangulation" and "qgis:dissolve" like so

```
delone_triangles = processing.runalg("qgis:delaunaytriangulation", assistant_layer, None)['OUTPUT']               
delaunay_layer = processing.getObject(delone_triangles)
#some code later
dissolved = processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", delaunay_layer,
                                          True, '', None)['OUTPUT']
dissolved_layer = processing.getObject(dissolved)
```

and from what I can gather what it does is it creates temporary files, saves the path to those files in both the *delone_triangles* and *dissolved* variables respectively and then uses that file to create the *delaunay_layer* and *dissolved_layer* objects. So with each iteration it essentially creates more  unnecessary files. According to their documentation both of those algorithms have an output parameter, but I haven't been able to figure out how to properly use it and the documentation is not helpful
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/delaunaytriangulation.html

https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/delaunaytriangulation.html

What I wanna do is I wanna set up both the delaunay_layer layers before and then have those algorithms save their outputs onto those layers. Is that possible? How do I do that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could specify your output by replacing `None` with a path where you want your layers saved. E.g. `C:\Users\You\Desktop\Result folder\delone_triangles.shp`. That way, the shapefile called _"delone_triangles.shp"_ in the _"Result folder"_ will be overwritten everytime the script is run without having to create temporary files.

Comment: Like so?
delone_triangles = processing.runalg("qgis:delaunaytriangulation", assistant_layer, 'D:\QGIS Chugiak\Result folder\delone_triangles.shp')['OUTPUT']
When I do that it works on the first iteration and on the subsequent ones the program doesn't seem to overwrite or modify the contents of the layer.  Or rather it seems to restore it to the previous state, even if I delete all the features from the layer by the end of the loop.

Comment: Are you looking to _add_ more contents to the same layer after each iteration? Also, not sure about others, but I had problems saving shapefiles to the QGIS directory so I avoid doing that and usually save my shapefiles in a folder on the desktop.

Comment: I'm looking to replace them, but that's just a simple matter of adding then removing (if overwriting isn't an option). I'll try saving to desktop.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing. Here have some logs:
loop 1
i = 11534182
Features in total 4296
Features on assistant_layer 214
Creating Delaunay triangles ...
54
Features on delaunay_layer 421
Computing edges max length ...
Removing features ...
Dissolving Delaunay triangles ...
Saving data ...
Features on assistant_layer 0
Features on delaunay_layer 0
Features on dissolved_layer 0


loop 2
i = 11543922
Features in total 4296
Features on assistant_layer 1297
Creating Delaunay triangles ...
54
Features on delaunay_layer 421
Computing edges max length ...

Comment: I'm not as experienced as others in this matter so hopefully others will advise. Saying that, do you have the **layer loaded in QGIS** when you are running the code? It could explain why the shapefile is not being modified if it's already in use.

Comment: You mean as in added to the registry and shown in the app as a layer? No and besides, my assistant_layer is added to the registry and modified just fine. If you mean something else then how do I check if it's loaded?

Comment: _You mean as in added to the registry and shown in the app as a layer?_ - Yes, that was what I meant. Apologies I couldn't be of help, as I said, hopefully others will advise as I am still learning on how to use python in QGIS :)

Comment: I also tried: delone_triangles = processing.runalg("qgis:delaunaytriangulation", assistant_layer, 'C:\Users\Stach\Desktop\Shapefiles\delone_triangles' + str(iteration) + '.shp')['OUTPUT'] Which granted, would create 6 * #iterations worth of files, but in theory should run. In practice it refuses to create a file on the 4th iteration.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks anyway. At least you tried and I think I did make some small progress here.